# How to login to gmail using selenium? My code is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to log in to Gmail using my code. Please help

```
public class first_test {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    @BeforeTest
    public void tearup()
    {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com");

    }

  @Test
  public void mail() throws InterruptedException  {
      WebElement email=driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
      email.click();
      email.sendKeys("sharfulumair");
      WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.id("//*[@name=\"password\"]"));
      password.click();
      password.sendKeys("abcd");
  }


  @AfterTest  
  public void teardown()
  {
    driver.close();
  }


}
```

The error message I got is:

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"identifierId"}

Answer (score 0):

Try using wait before accessing the webelement.

```
public void mail() throws InterruptedException  {
      new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("identifierId")));
      WebElement email=driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId"));
      ...............
  }
```